# Displaying html dropdown list selection with javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select

I'm trying to use js to display a users selection in an HTML  dropdown list after their selection is submitted. I've searched for hours and tried several different methods and none of them have worked so far. This is my current code:

```
<script>
    var e = document.getElementById("user_engine");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    function showEngineChoice() {
        document.getElementById('engine').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("strUser").value;
    }
</script>
<label><b>What type of engine would you like in your favorite car?</b></label>
<select name="engine_types" id="user_engine">
    <option value="1">In-Line V6</option>
    <option value="2">3.8L 4-cylinder</option>
    <option value="3">Twin Turbo V10</option>
    <option value="4">RS-68 Rocket Engine</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" onclick="showEngineChoice()"><br />
<label>You chose: </label><br />
<p><span id="engine"></span></p><br />
<label>Nice Choice!</label>
```

I've tried a few other methods, and each time I run the code, clicking the submit button after making a selection does nothing. What am I not doing right?

Comment: Where is your `#strUser` element defined ?

Comment: I can't see how `var  e = document.getElementById("user_engine");` can be defined ,  since your `<script></script>` is preceding the `#user_engine` element **AND** your code appears to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is preceding your document body. Which means the elements you are referencing using `getElementById` are not defined. Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/pablo-tavarez/pen/NwjrYm?editors=1010

```
   <script>
    // await a fully loaded DOM
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

      // prefetch element references
      var ue = document.getElementById("user_engine");
      var e = document.getElementById('engine');


      // define (global) onsubmit function
      window.showEngineChoice = function showEngineChoice() {
         // update content with CURRENTLY selected option
          e.innerHTML = ue.options[ue.selectedIndex].value;
      }
    });
</script>
<label>
    <b>What type of engine would you like in your favorite car?</b>
</label>
<select name="engine_types" id="user_engine">
    <option value="1">In-Line V6</option>
    <option value="2">3.8L 4-cylinder</option>
    <option value="3">Twin Turbo V10</option>
    <option value="4">RS-68 Rocket Engine</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" onclick="showEngineChoice()"><br />
<label>You chose: </label><br />
<p>
    <span id="engine"></span>
</p><br />
<label>Nice Choice!</label>
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm still a newbie with JavaScript so I probably wouldn't have caught that but your code makes sense. I just replaced .value with .text to return the selected choice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome I'm glad you understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
     document.getElementById('engine').innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById("strUser").value;
```

change 'strUser' to 'user-engine'

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fact that you need to select the correct element using `user_engine` instead of `strUser`, you might also want to replace `.value` with `.selectedOptions[0].text`.

The `value` property returns the value of the option - i.e. 1,2,3 etc. Whereas when you access `selectedOptions[0].text` it gives you the text of the first selected option.

Also, you'd have to keep the script after the HTML content in order to ensure that the elements are loaded to DOM by the time script runs.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("user_engine");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

function showEngineChoice() {
  document.getElementById('engine').innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("user_engine").selectedOptions[0].text;
}
```

```html
<label><b>What type of engine would you like in your favorite car?</b></label>
<select name="engine_types" id="user_engine">
    <option value="1">In-Line V6</option>
    <option value="2">3.8L 4-cylinder</option>
    <option value="3">Twin Turbo V10</option>
    <option value="4">RS-68 Rocket Engine</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" onclick="showEngineChoice()"><br />
<label>You chose: </label><br />
<p><span id="engine"></span></p><br />
<label>Nice Choice!</label>
```